# Mysql query update from 2 column of its current value

Tags: mysql

MySQL version   5.1.63-cll
Using phpmyadmin to edit

So i have this table ps_layered_price_index
i want to edit/update column:-

```
price_min AND
price_max 
(updating the current value+10)

where column(id_product) = ALL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update every row of your table, then you could try something like this :

```
UPDATE 
 ps_layered_price_index
SET 
 price_min = price_min + 10,
 price_max = price_max + 10
```

For a single row :

```
UPDATE 
 ps_layered_price_index
SET 
 price_min = price_min + 10,
 price_max = price_max + 10
WHERE 
 id_product = 87
```

Comment: thanks will try it out, what if i want to choose like where id_product=87

Comment: thanks.wll try it out,what if i want to do like where id_product=87   ??causee i keep getting syntax error with it..zzz